# Service invoked too many times for one day: gmail read

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that polls the inbox every minute and then does some processing accordingly.  I am receiving this error:

> Service invoked too many times for one day: gmail read.

What is the limit per day?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

out of date>>gmail reads are capped at 10000/day.

See current quotas> choose the Quota Limits tab>
 [See Quotas here.](https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard)